# MySQL keyring component (not plugin) not loading on server startup

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, innodb

Problem:

- There is no indication mysqld is actually reading the server manifest and/or the keyring component configuration file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

System Info:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- MySQL 8.0.29

Details:

- All files are in the default locations where "sudo apt-get install mysql-server" puts them.
- mysql-server package came from Ubuntu repos.

What I've tried:

- Per the MySQL docs, I created "a global manifest file named mysqld.my in the mysqld installation directory", and tried placing it in the following locations without success:
  (NOTE: Owner:group:perms == root:mysql:640)

  - /usr ('basedir' location)
  - /usr/sbin/ (mysqld binary location) [file is currently here]
  - /var/lib/mysql ('datadir' location) [ASIDE: If I were using a global and a local manifest, the local manifest goes here according to the mysql docs.]
  - /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ ('plugin_dir' location)
- Per the MySQL docs, I created "a global configuration file named component_keyring_file.cnf in the directory where the component_keyring_file library file is installed" in the following location:
  (NOTE: Owner:group:perms == root:mysql:640)

  - /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ ('plugin_dir' location. File 'component_keyring_file.so' does exist here.)
- I used the following test with an initial condition that mysqld was not running:

  1. Place the global manifest in one of the folders listed.
  2. Start mysqld. ("sudo service mysql start")
  3. Verify mysqld started. ("sudo service mysql status")
  4. Check keyring component status: mysql -v -v -v -uREDACTED -pREDACTED -e "SELECT * FROM performance_schema.keyring_component_status;"
  5. Stop mysqld. ("sudo service mysql stop")
  6. Verify mysqld stopped. ("sudo service mysql status")
  7. Repeat at step #1 for next file location.

  In all cases the SELECT query returned "Empty set".
- Finally, I tried changing the permissions on the global manifest to 660 in the hope that I would see a warning in the MySQL error.log, but there is still nothing in the error.log that indicates the keyring component loaded before InnoDB is initialized.
  (Reason: The MySQL docs stated "server access to a manifest file
  should be read only. For example, a mysqld.my server manifest file
  may be owned by root and be read/write to root, but should be read
  only to the account used to run the MySQL server. If the manifest
  file is found during startup to be read/write to that account, the
  server writes a warning to the error log suggesting that the file be
  made read only.")

End Result: I'm running out of ideas, and I'm hoping one of you can point me in the right direction.

Other info:

- I'm aware there is plenty of info on how to configure the keyring plugin, but apparently the component is newer and offers more features/flexibility which is why I was attempting to use it.
- If it helps, here's where I started from on the MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-data-encryption.html#innodb-data-encryption-about

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've been through the documentation very thoroughly. It looks to me like it should be working.

Things you might check:

1. Is the plugin directory configured? What is the output of `show variables like 'plugin_dir';`
2. Are you using AppArmor? Run `sudo aa-status`. If you are, and mysql is in one of the enforce profiles then you can either put it into a complain profile (`sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld`) or use the mysql profile in appArmor, e.g. `cat /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld | sudo apparmor_parser -a`. Note that you might need to update the profile with your specific paths for the encryption keyring file.

Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem that you described here. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and mysql 8.031. I went through the exact same steps that you did with the component keyring file and the query "SELECT * FROM performance_schema.keyring_component_status;" returns "Empty set". Let me know if anyone has updates on this.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/538525)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your mysqld file is located in /usr/sbin/? In my case, a symbolic link associated with mysqld file is there.  So I created mysqld.my file in /usr/libexec and it's working.

[root@mysql-server libexec]# pwd
/usr/libexec
[root@mysql-server libexec]# cat mysqld.my
{
"read_local_manifest": true
}
[root@mysql-server libexec]#

mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.keyring_component_status;
Connection id:    8
Current database: *** NONE ***

+---------------------+------------------------+
| STATUS_KEY          | STATUS_VALUE           |
+---------------------+------------------------+
| Component_name      | component_keyring_file |
| Author              | Oracle Corporation     |
| License             | GPL                    |
| Implementation_name | component_keyring_file |
| Version             | 1.0                    |
| Component_status    | Disabled               |
| Data_file           |        |
| Read_only           |        |
+---------------------+------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>